# How do you delay a gui's operation without delaying the interface?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, delay

I'm creating a flash card program and want to have a few seconds delay between when the question pops up vs the answer. I've been trying using thread.sleep...

```
question.setText(questionString);

if(timed.isSelected())
{
     delay();//uses thread.sleep
}

answer.setText(questionString);
```

The sleep executes before the question appears on the gui, so it just reappears with both the question and the answer instantly. Question and answer are just JPanels and timed is a JRadioButton.

So onto the actual question, is there anyway I can delay the answer appearing so that it flows nicely? As if I was using println's in the cmd prompt maybe.

Comment: Have you had a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)?

Comment: @Quirliom: add a little more detail and make that an answer. to the original poster, yes, use a Swing Timer. Of course the devil will be in the details, so give it a try, and if you get stuck, post your attempt here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swing: Enabling Buttons With Delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534844/swing-enabling-buttons-with-delay)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thread.sleep actually pauses the Thread you run it on. This can be hazardous when you are running on the Event Dispatch Thread because you essentially stop any GUI updates while the sleep run, such that you set the text, and then stop the GUI updating until you set the text with the answer - the question can never get drawn.

For a non blocking alternative to timing, have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) which looks at the [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class. This class allows you to specify a delay, and an action to be completed after that delay has passed, without pausing your Threads.